How can we make changes to package.json if verdaccio requires changes to be stashed or commit?
I use a verdaccio script for updating our package-lock.
How can this verdaccio script run on modified files?
I tried to commit and stash, but if I update the versions of packages in the package.json, those changes are lost before the script runs.
